# Rotating strings in Python

Tags: python, string

I was trying to make the string `HELLO` to `OHELL` in Python. But couldn't get any way to rotate it without working with loops. How to code for it in just 1-2 lines so that I could get the desired pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I think *reverse* is the wrong term here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can slice and add strings:

```
>>> s = 'HELLO'
>>> s[-1] + s[:-1]
'OHELL'
```

This gives you the last character:

```
>>> s[-1]
'O'
```

and this everything but the last:

```
>>> s[:-1]
'HELL'
```

Finally, add them with `+`.

Comment: How should I do if the list is numbers? because I got error : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: This is for strings. Maybe you men a list of numbers `[1, 2, 3]`? `>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> L[-1:] + L[:-1]
[3, 1, 2]`

Answer (score 16):

Here is one way:

```
def rotate(strg, n):
    return strg[n:] + strg[:n]

rotate('HELLO', -1)  # 'OHELL'
```

Alternatively, [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) ("double-ended queue") is optimised for queue-related operations. It has a dedicated rotate() method:

```
from collections import deque

items = deque('HELLO')
items.rotate(1)

''.join(items)  # 'OHELL'
```

Comment: I like that answer because it also works with empty strings.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I use to rotate strings in Python3:

To rotate left by n:

```
def leftShift(text,n):
    return text[n:] + text[:n]
```

To rotate right by n:

```
def rightShift(text,n):
    return text[-n:] + text[:-n]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way of looking at it...

```
s = 'HELLO'
for r in range(5):
    print(s[r:] + s[:r])


HELLO
ELLOH
LLOHE
LOHEL
OHELL
```

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Mike Müller's answer:

```
s = 'HELLO'
s = s[-1] + s[:-1]
```

I would like to share another way of looking at `s[:-1]`

```
s[0:-1]
```

This means that it is starting from the start and including everything except for s[-1].
I hope this helped.