# moving position of character within an item in list

Tags: python, list, items

If i had a list e.g.

```
['Hello', 'what', 'is', 'your', 'name']
```

what method lets you move the position of a character within the item itself and store it. So `'Hello'` could be changed to `'elloH'` by moving first character to the end and the same applied to rest of the items.

Comment: string slicing in list comprehension maybe

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48607319/rotating-strings-in-python

Answer (score 2):

You could use [slicing](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) and indexing:

```
def shift(s):
    return s[1:] + s[0]

data = ['Hello', 'what', 'is', 'your', 'name']

result = [shift(s) for s in data]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['elloH', 'hatw', 'si', 'oury', 'amen']
```

The statement `result = [shift(s) for s in data]` is known as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), is the *equivalent* of the following:

```
result = []
for s in data:
    result.append(shift(s))
```

Finally another alternative is to use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
result = list(map(shift, data))
```

The function map applies shift to each element of data, but it returns (in Python 3) an iterable so you need to convert it to list.

Answer (score 2):

just rebuild the list and generate new strings with slicing & addition:

```
lst = ['Hello', 'what', 'is', 'your', 'name']

result = [x[1:]+x[0] if x else "" for x in lst]
```

result:

```
['elloH', 'hatw', 'si', 'oury', 'amen']
```

(note the ternary expression which allows robustness to empty strings, since int the case of empty strings `x[0]` would raise an `IndexError`. Without a ternary expression, we could use `[x[1:]+x[0:1] for x in lst]` which does the same thing)

Answer (score 2):

Check the below code :

```
mylist = ['Hello', 'what', 'is', 'your', 'name']

mylist = [(mylist[i][1:] + mylist[i][0:1]) for i in range(0,len(mylist))]

print(mylist)
```

Output :

```
['elloH', 'hatw', 'si', 'oury', 'amen']
```

Comment: Why not iterate over the list directly without `range`?

Comment: the `[0:1]` part is (maybe unwillingly) protecting against empty strings, but the part with `range` and indices is very unpythonic

Comment: @bereal Iterating over the list will also do. Thanks for the suggestion.